# Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 LTS "Failed to recover vector for irq 44"

Tags: 14.04, boot, server

I just installed Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 LTS on a circa 2009 Dell R900 server.  When it boots up and is merely sitting at the prompt awaiting login credentials, I get the message:

```
Failed to recover vector for irq 44
```

It occurs around 60 seconds after either a restart or cold boot, and my cursory internet searches don't return anything.

[Screenshot highlighted in yellow here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jyv5.jpg)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried updating the BIOS/UEFI?  Have you updated all of the packages and rebooted?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did just update the BIOS, but I'll go ahead and confirm that the latest packages are installed as well.

Comment: Whelp, no such luck.  The issue continues to persist after the updates and reboot.

 I'm looking through dmesg right now, but so far I've not come across anything. 

[I'm looking into this "Debugging IRQ Problems" page now...](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingIRQProblems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the warning(error?) was coming from one of the servers (5) Ethernet ports.  I only need one port anyway, so I disabled ports 2-5 and the error stopped appearing.

I don't know if I would technically call this solved (because it's probably a driver issue), but the problem has been effectively mitigated for my purposes.

Thanks!